# Casting a generic class to parent C#

Tags: c#, generics

My question may be old and stupid, but please help me.

Here's my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var first  = new ChildClass();
        var result = new List<ParentGenericClass<ITypeInterface>>();
        result.Add(first);
    }
}

public interface ITypeInterface { }
public class TypeClass : ITypeInterface { }
public class ParentGenericClass<TObject> where TObject : ITypeInterface { }
public class ChildClass : ParentGenericClass<TypeClass> { }
```

`TypeClass` is child of `ITypeInterface` and `ChildClass` is child of `ParentGenericClass`.

Why can't I convert `ChildClass` to `ParentGenericClass<ITypeInterface>`?
I think it should work fine.

What am I missing?

I've searched with keywords like `generic`, `cast`, and so on but I can't find a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *variance* issue and the use of the covarient `out` is only supported on interfaces and not Classes.

> **Covariance** Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.

The fact is, `ChildClass` is actually not the same as `ParentGenericClass<ITypeInterface>`

One option is to refactor to something like this

```
public interface IParentGenericClass<out TObject> where TObject : ITypeInterface
{
}

public class ParentGenericClass<TObject> : IParentGenericClass<TObject>
where TObject : ITypeInterface
{
}
...

var result = new List<IParentGenericClass<ITypeInterface>>();
result.Add(first);
```